# The Wobbling Staircase Function

Tags: geometry

Define the *wobbling staircase function* as follows:

> **Informally:** The wobbling staircase function consists of $3$ connected line segments with alternating 'size' of gradients. That is, the gradient of the second line segment is **smaller** than the first and that of the third is **greater** than the second.

Note: if you sketch this then it does look like a wobbly staircase!

> **Formally:** Assume that the first line segment begins at the origin. If the endpoint of the first line segment is $(a,d)$, that of the second is $(b,e)$ aand that of the third is $(c,f)$, then the wobbling staircase function is $$\begin{align}y=\begin{cases}\frac dax,\quad &0\le x\le a\\\frac{e-d}{b-a}x+\frac{d(b-a)-a(e-d)}{b-a},\quad & a<x\le b\\\frac{d-e}{c-b}x+\frac{e(c-b)-b(f-e)}{c-b},\quad &b<x\le c\end{cases}\end{align}$$ This means that we have $$\frac da>\frac{e-d}{b-a}\implies \frac de>\frac ab$$

Define also the line joining the origin and $(c,f)$: $$y_{\text{tot}}=\frac fcx.$$

---

> **Question:** On what condition(s) is $y_{\text{tot}}$ always above each of the line segments, except for the points $(0,0)$ and $(c,f)$?

Note that this is equivalent to asking when $y_{\text{tot}}$ does not cross the second line segment.

> **Bonus Question:** What if I extend this is $2k+1$ connected line segments? What would the constraints then be?

Comment: As long as the line is above the first point $(a,d)$, you're good. For more connected line segments, just check the odd-numbered points.

Comment: By the way, referring to it as "*the* wobbling staircase" is wrong; your function should be called "*a* wobbling staircase" (since there is not just one unique wobbling staircase).

Comment: It is not equivalent to not crossing the second line segment.  $y_{tot}$ could be below them all except at the endpoints.  Just turn one where it is above them all upside down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informally, what you want is for the vector $\left(\matrix{c\\f}\right)$ to lie "on the left" of the vector $\left(\matrix{a\\d}\right)$.

Formally, this is saying that the basis $\left(\left(\matrix{c\\f}\right),\left(\matrix{a\\d}\right)\right)$ is negatively oriented, which you check by computing the sign of its determinant. Hence $y_\text{tot}$ lies above all line segments if and only if $$cd-af<0.$$

For more line segments, you have more determinants to compute.